# Woocommerce API Read Only On Products

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce

I want to give a user ability only to view (read) products using the Woocommerce API only.  I have looked everywhere and although there are role "permissions" for read_product, it doesn't seem to be linked to the api features or inherit the user's web browsing permissions.  So when trying to view the read results, i get the response `"code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view"`, 401 error...    Note: It is not an api authentication issue, I can view products and authenticate totally fine using administrator level keys on basic auth no problem.

I found this through digging and wondering how I would use this hook to see the "read_product" permission and grant the API user read access to the products they are querying on the API with this role permission.  Unfortunately there is about little documentation on how this works but seems to be what I need to use.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_check_permissions', 'my_woocommerce_rest_check_permissions', 90, 4 );

function my_woocommerce_rest_check_permissions( $permission, $context, $object_id, $post_type  ){

}
```

Anyone done this or know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Checkpoints

- Did you generate API key for woocommerce?
- If so, you should be able to get response code [200] when you send 'get' request to
  `https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products`

refer to official docs

https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#rest-api-keys